# Traversal using iterators (post increment operator++(int), begin(order) and end()) for Binary search tree in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, iteration, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am new to Data structures using C++

So, I am trying to implement an iterator that traverses through a binary search tree using an iterator class nested inside the BST class. I also have a struct node and insert method in the private section of the BST class.

The ++ operator is a post-increment operator that is supposed to move to the next node. But since we have 3 different types of traversals in trees, I am confused about how to iterate the operator.
I have 3 different functions of void type for inorder, pre, and post-order traversal which is done using one common stack. How do I connect these 3 functions to the iterator class?
any suggestions??

```
            iterator operator ++ (int)
            {   
            
            }
            iterator begin(trav order) //trav is an enum class with types of traversals
            {
                //??
            }
            iterator end()
            {
                //??
            }
```

Comment: Once you have a tree, do an inorder traversal and store the visited nodes in a vector. Then form an iterator class on this vector. The problem with this is that you'll need to do an inorder traversal everytime the tree gets modified. Second way is to maintain two pointers `prev` and `next` in each node. Whenever you insert a value, update these pointers when coming back from a recursive call. There will be two special cases: inorder successor and preorder successor which you'll need to take care of. Similar will be the approach when deleting a value although it will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Inorder successor and inorder predecessor*

Comment: Is the BST balanced?